# Can't get SAFEARRAY to work with Interop

Tags: c#, c++, interop, atl

I have an ATL COM Server, where the method for the interface is

```
STDMETHODIMP CWrapper::RUN(long iDataSize, SAFEARRAY** iData)
```

and the MIDL for this function looks like

```
[id(1), helpstring("method RUN")] HRESULT RUN([in] long nSize, [in, size_is(nSize)] SAFEARRAY(_MyDataType*)* iData);
```

I import the tlb from this project using tlbimp, so I can use native arrays. I then call it from C# as follows

```
 m_ServerWrapper.RUN(iInputs.Length,ref iInputs)
```

where Inputs is already allocated and filled with another COM object from inside my C# program. Now, when I call into the C++ wrapper, I have a `BadPtr` for my safearray and the call into a subsequent COM object from `CWrapper::RUN` fails with the array not making it to the final dll. It shows up as unallocated. Does anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT: I should have stated that the array looks just fine in C#.

EDIT2: The debugger shows `iData` safearray of `IDispatch* = 0x0000000 <Bad Ptr>, 5, 0x0000000 <Bad Ptr>({lpvtbl = 0xblahblah},...`.
So it looks like some of my information is getting there.

Comment: Is _MyDataType defined in the IDL as well? If not, you should do it in there. Another thing: why do you need nSize? SAFEARRAY maintains its own size.

Answer (score 0):

A normal C# array is not the same as a SAFEARRAY.  I think you have to make your own:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SafeArray
{
    public ushort   dimensions;  
    public ushort   features;    
    public uint     elementSize; 
    public uint     locks;       
    public IntPtr   dataPtr;     
    public uint     elementCount;
    public int      lowerBound;  
}
```

Then use Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem() to create the memory.  Fill in all the data and then pass it.

Comment: All of the docs I can find seem to indicate the interop layer should marshal the array to a safearray